# TransformException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw;

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, flutter

I've tried following the Google's Flutter Firebase Codelab. added the dependencies as they suggest, but the moment I add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line to my **app/build.gradle** my app stops compiling with the following error:

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw;

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaw;
```

Based on my research of other similar threads this exception means that something defines something more than once, but I have troubles identifying that something, because the zzcaw part in the exception is different every time.

My app is an empty new project that has no other dependencies than the ones the codelab suggests. Also one of the threads mentions that I need to update Google Play Tools, but the SDK manager says that I don't have any updates. I've also tried changing the version of the google-services package and the project starts building with version <=2.2.0 but the app won't start:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As you may guess, I've tried enabling multiDexEnabled and upgrading gradle as one of the issues on GitHub suggested, but to no avail.

**flutter --doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.2.10-pre.39, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.2.10-pre.39 at E:\VSProjects\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision d121cbc80d (3 days ago), 2018-04-08 09:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision d2b69fec75
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.46.0.flutter-09e1766e6c

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\AndroidSDK
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 26.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\AndroidSDK
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.22.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Dart Code extension version 2.11.2

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: "^3.0.0"
```

P.S.

I have no problems building or running flutter apps with no reference to the google-services plugin.

Comment: You don't even have any Google play services included in `dependencies {}` block

Comment: Have you added anything to your pubspec.yaml yet? Some of the firebase plugins perhaps?

Comment: Try to `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project.

Comment: @cricket_007, I have a reference only to the google_sign_in plugin as the codelab suggests. I've added my pubspec file to the question.

Comment: @betorcs, unfortunately doing flutter clean does not help :(

Comment: I don't know Flutter, but are you trying to use Google Auth? I also don't know what that sign in library is https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after days of experiments, I've finally figured it out. As @cricket_007 and @rmtmckenzie mentioned in the comment to the question I did not have any of the Google/Firebase services added to the **pubspec.yaml** file.

I added firebase_analytics for starter but it did not help. Through trial and error I found out that I had to lower the version of `com.google.gms:google-services` to `3.1.0` too. Now I'm able to compile *and* open my app.